# Is it possible to parallelize with fortran 95 using mpif90 and mpirun?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran95

I would like to know if it is possible to parallelize a program in fortran 95 using the mpif90 instruction to compile and mpirun to run because I would like to use the FORALL instruction. On the other hand, in fortran 90 is it possible to use FOR to replace FORALL in fortran 95? How should the FOR cycle be built?

Comment: Are you wondering whether `mpif90` is able to compile Fortran 90 code only, rather than Fortran 95, 2003, 2008, 2018?

Comment: Yes. I don't know if mpif90 is able to compile fortran 95 or if there is another way to compile a parallel program in fortran 95.

Comment: The _f90_ in mpif90 is a misnomer.  If you have Fortran code conforming to any recent Fortran Standard, then mpif90 can be used to compile it.  Note, `FORALL` is a Fortran construct and has nothing to do with MPI.  How any specific compiler handles `FORALL` is, of course, compiler dependent, and may in fact not be executed in parallel.

Comment: 1) Do you mean that the following instructions are correct to compile and run a program in Fortran 95?

mpif90 prog.f95 -o prog
mpirun -np # ./prog

Comment: 2) I have been reading Fortran 90/95 for Scientists and Enginners by Chapman and this book give an explanation why FORALL is better than Do loops in massively parallel computers. I am right?

Comment: If `mpf90` recognizes the `.f95` suffix, then yes, `mpif90 -o prog prog.f95` should compile the program.  If `.f95` isn't recognized either rename the file or use a compiler option.  Never looked at Chapman's book, but `FORALL` is not all that it seems.  Also note, `FORALL` is not a loop construct.  It is an assignment construct.

Comment: Worth noting perhaps that `forall` has been declared obsolescent in recent editions of the Fortran standard, a status equivalent to what many other languages call 'deprecated'.  Chapman's advice might have been reasonable 20 years ago, but is, at best, outdated now, at worst positively misleading.  Investigate instead `do concurrent`.

Comment: For all is not better than DO loops. It can make things worse. Do not use it for new code and certainly not to speed anything up. Nested DO lloops are just fine.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I have other question. Do you know if there is any instruction in Fortran (90/95) that replaces nested do loops efficciently? I know that in C ++ the For statement is used instead of nested do loops (or for loops) to parallelize  a program efficiently. Somethig like to:

h = (i = .., j = ..., k = ...)
For (h = ..., ...., ...)
end For
where i, j, k are the indexes of the nested do loops (for loops).

Comment: You are looking for OpenMP or OpenACC.  Neither is a part of the Fortran standard, but one or both tend to be supported by modern compilers.

Comment: Relevant: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/286446

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark , Is it possible to use "do concurrent" with MPI?. Because I need work with many nested do loops.

Comment: Yes it's possible.  But you may be trying to run before you can walk.  Forget MPI for a while, Fortran compilers are very very very good at optimising simple loops (nested or otherwise) and you may be able to achieve good enough performance using `do concurrent` alone and without MPI.  But your question, and the commentary, have gone on too long.  Write some code and when  you have further questions ask them.